# How to parse operator from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, class, parsing, operators

I want to parse an operator say "+" from the string "+" which i entered as command-line argument at run-time and then add two integers say 'a' and 'b'.

So how can i perform the above task?

Comment: What is the grammar? You need that before parsing.

Comment: if say i enter "10+20" in commandline then how can i get the answer as "30"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What nobody so far is telling you is that to recognize arithmetic expressions in general you need to use, or write, a parser. Have a look for the Shunting-yard algorithm, recursive descent expression parsing, etc.

Comment: ok. i would hav to explore it a little more than.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 1.7, you can use a switch to test for each possible operator and then do the corresponding operation:

```
switch(operator){
    case("+"): result = a + b; break;
    case("-"): result = a - b; break;
}
```

For older versions of Java can be done using `if` statements.

Comment: Or `operator.charAt(0)`

Comment: if say i enter "10+20" in commandline then how can i get the answer as "30"?

Comment: That's another question. Why didn't you ask that?

Comment: i thought to try it later on if i could get some hint on this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (string.equals("+")) {
    System.out.println("The result is " + (a + b));
}
```

Comment: if say i enter "10+20" in commandline then how can i get the answer as "30"?